Windows 11 does not connect to Bind9 DNS Server on Ubuntu Server
I've setup a Bind9 DNS server on Ubuntu Server 22.04 with a test domain name called nonxdom.com. The Ubuntu Server is on a Virtual Box installed on a Windows 11 machine.
Everything works fine on Ubuntu Server when using nslookup and dig. However, it seems that Windows 11 cannot reach nonxdom.com on Ubuntu Server.
I've entered 192.168.27.9 as the preferred DNS server in the Wireless Adapater settings that I use to connect to the internet. Sometimes it'll work, loading the index page. But most times it won't. I have to set the preferred DNS server to Automatic and then back to 192.168.27.9. A few hours ago it worked fine. After restarting Windows, it's the same thing.
What needs to be done so I don't have to keep doing the steps above?

You should try to localize and simplify the symptom by entering "a" DNS server, or "one" DNS server. Windows may use multiple forms of name resolution in parallel, on multiple adapters in parallel, and even multiple DNS servers in parallel.
